# Meaning of 'Although the meaning of the word "continuous" seems intuitively clear…'

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

In my math book there is a sentence as,

> Although the meaning of the word "continuous" seems intuitively clear
> to most people, it is not obvious how a good definition of this idea should be formulated.

I couldn't grasp what the author is trying to say with this sentence. This comes under the topic of continuity. The books is "calculus" and the author is Tom Apostol. I apologize for this weird question that I am asking. It's both an overlap of math and English, so I thought it will more appropriate to ask this here.

Comment: You'll have to spell out what you don't understand about the sentence. It seems clear to me.

Comment: @ColinFine- I understand the first phrase when I read it alone but I couldn't understand what he means when he says "this idea" , Is it the idea of 'continuous' or the idea of 'continuity'.

Comment: Both. Either. I don't see why you need to distinguish whether he is talking about _contiinous_ or _continuity_ - if one is difficult to define precisely, so will the other be.

Comment: @ColinFine- What does this mean "if one is difficult to define precisely, so will the other be" ?

Comment: If "continous" is difficult to define precisely, then "continuity" will be difficult to define precisely, and if "continuity" is difficult to define precisely then "continuous" will be difficult to define precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This idea" refers to the idea discussed in the first part of the sentence.  That idea is the idea of "the meaning of the word 'continuous'"

But the idea of this word *is* the idea of continuity.

You can't say "the idea of continuous" since "continuous" is not a noun.  Grammatically that doesn't make sense.

Here is a similar example

> Joe is very happy. That is very important for him.

So what is important for Joe?  Answer: Happiness is important for him. Grammatically you need the answer to be a noun, so "Happy is very important" doesn't make sense.

Similarly:

> Although the meaning of the word "happy" seems intuitively clear to most people, it is not obvious how a good definition of this idea should be formulated.

The idea is the idea of happiness.

Comment: -Thanks man, This was very important to me.

Answer (score 1):

Apostol is warning you that the everyday ordinary English meaning of the word "continuous" is not precise enough to do good mathematics with. Mathematicians have invented a relatively complex definition you will have to master.

This kind of vocabulary problem is common. Mathematics always requires precise definitions for words that carry a certain amount of ambiguity. For example, the everyday word "or" usually is interpreted as exclusive. You can have cake or ice cream but not both. In mathematics "or" always means what you can say in everyday English as "and/or".

Comment: @EthanBolker- Is 'the idea' means the word 'continuous' or the word 'continuity'.

Comment: Both "continuous" and "continuity" suggest "changing smoothly without sudden jumps". That's the idea Apostol will make mathematically precise.